# VueJs: How to determine in a watcher, whether the component is mounted?

Tags: vue.js, components, hook, lifecycle

Seems like a simple requirement, and of course I could maintain my own flag using the [lifecycle hooks](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html). See also https://forum.vuejs.org/t/check-if-mounted-was-called/88177/6 for a similar question.

However, I prefer to use something already build-in. I am sure, VueJs maintains the lifecycle state somewhere.

Here's my watcher, simplified:

```
@Watch('openId')
private onOpenIdChanged() {
    this.submitSomething(); //But ONLY if it's mounted!
}
```

**How can I access the lifecycle state of the same component in a component's watcher, without using my own flag?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API for this, so the *only* correct answer is to maintain your own flag.

There is a private property on the component instance `_isMounted` which Vue uses internally (as of version 2.6.11).

Comment: Is this property documented somewhere, even if it's internal?

Comment: No it's not documented because it's a private implementation detail which should not be used publicly. It could be removed in the next non-major version and break your code, hence why it should not be used.